# Database recording of information about changes with n-m relationship

Tags: sql-server, database, versioning, audit

I have a (SQL Server) database where I'm tracking changes on a table; the requirement from the customer is to be able to see the "picture" of any point back in time, specifying the requested date.
What I have done so far is to implement a `HistoryTable`, following the idea of [Log trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_trigger), with database triggers to store historical data.

Now, the requirement changed, and I need to add a many-to-many (n-m) relationship to the original table. Of course, the linked data set (n-m relationship) should be "versioned" as well, changing over time as the original table.

My first idea is to refer the n-m relation with a "fake ID" in the main table, that is: a normal (int) field, and not the primary key (which is not changing over time). In this way, I could change that ID over time, for instance:

Version 1:

```
Version 1
ID  RelID  Data
5   5      Version 1

Version 2
ID  RelID  Data
5   5      Version 2

Version 3
ID  RelID  Data
5   6      Version 3
```

In this example, the n-m relation did not change between version 1 and 2, but changed in version 3.

This is fine, but my questions are:

- Whenever the n-m relation version changes, how can I get a new RelID that is unique in the table?
- Another option: can I refer the n-m relation to both the ID and the RelID (that is unique for sure)?
- Is there any smarter solutions than mine?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario sounds like it could easily fit the data warehousing concept of a slowly changing dimension. Generally the type-2 slowly changing dimension are considered the most useful. These record a start and end date for each version of the row and the current row simply stores `NULL` for the end date.

Basically you would add to additional columns  to your bridging table to record the start and end date of that row's version. Where the EndDate is `NULL` you know that is the current row version.

So your table would end up looking like:

```
 ID | RelID | StartDate  | EndDate
----+-------+------------+------------
 05 |   06  | 2014-10-01 | NULL
 05 |   05  | 2014-09-10 | 2014-10-01
 05 |   03  | 2014-09-10 | NULL
```

From this data you can tell that ID 05 was related to RelID 05 until 2014-10-01 and it then it was related to RelID 06 and it is still related to RelID 03.

Then when you need the current relationship data you can simply say

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE EndDate IS NULL
```

and if you're looking back historically you can say

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE @selectionDate BETWEEN StartDate AND COALESCE(EndDate,GETDATE())
```

Without knowing more about your data structure I can't tell if this is a good fit for the problem you're trying to solve. But usually a many-to-many relationship needs a bridging table between the two tables of actual records to create a proper relationship and the Type-2 slowly changing dimension is a tried and true method of versioning rows in a data warehouse and that same concept can be applied anywhere you need historical versioning of records.

Comment: I found your answer in line with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719110/data-warehouse-slowly-changing-dimensions-with-many-to-many-relationships) related answer on SO. By the way, the attached [article](http://www.cibis.org.je/index.php/blog/2010/02/18/modelling-loading-a-slowly-changing-many-to-many-relationship/) is a very interesting reading as well. Thanks.